# How can i display permalink inside the excerpt paragraphs

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

im trying to show the permalink right inside/after the excerpt

the code that im using at a designated area in my theme is this

```
<div id="headline"> 
 <?php the_excerpt(); echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'" class="more-link">'; echo '[Read more...]'; echo '</a>';?> 
</div>
```

the result

```
<p>the excerpt here</p>
<a>permalink here</a>
```

how can i show the permalink inside the same paragraphs that the excerpt is displayed ?

`<p> the_excerpt; <a>permalink</a> </p>`

thanks all.

Comment: This is how i want it `<p> excerpt, <a>permalink</a></p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the following code in the functions.php fule of your theme

```
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
   global $post;
   return '<a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">[Read more...]</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

This codex entry has more details on how you can modify what the `excerpt` spits out : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt

Comment: @mauri no problem. Please mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem :) :http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above solution but it didn't solve my problem, the A tag still showed outside the P tags.  I solved my problem using get_the_excerpt(), which returned just the excerpt text without the P tags.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt